# "between" query for two date objects are returning wrong output in Realm

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I'm storing purchase transactions with a time-stamp (the exact same date-time object when the purchase was made). When I try to extract the result from a starting & ending date, It's giving wrong result.

Here's an example of the date objects/format I'm storing,

```
27-01-2016
27-02-2016
10-05-2016
27-05-2016
```

And this is the query for retrieving objects between two dates,

```
RealmResults<Transactions> result = realm.where(Transactions.class)
                .between("timestamp", start, end)
                .findAll();
```

Now for a given **starting date: 01-01-16** & **ending_date: 29-02-2016**, It's returning a single object 
**"27-01-2016"** which is incorrect.

Is there anything missing from my query?

Comment: Can you try with `greaterThanOrEqual("timestamp", start).lessThanOrEqual("timestamp", end);`?

Comment: I tested the case you described, it works fine... See https://gist.github.com/beeender/13e149a073c19164415ea571c404cc80 Can you reproduce it with some simple code piece so we can take a look? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For latest `Realm` versions we can use `between(String fieldName, Date from, Date to)`

If you use **"27-01-2016"** format reset this values before saving the `date`

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal.setTime(date);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


   RealmObject.setDbDate(cal.getTime());
```

Then you can query, make sure you set the `startDate` and `endDate` values **range** correctly

```
query.between(RealmObject.FIELD_DATE, startDate, endDate);
```

But, sometimes `between()` is not enough because it not allowed linked objects, for example when you search for all items where their childs(also RealmObject that contain date) match the date range.

Then you can use `greaterThanOrEqualTo(String fieldName, Date value)` and `lessThanOrEqualTo(String fieldName, Date value)`

```
             query.greaterThanOrEqualTo(RealmObject.FIELD_LINKED_OBJECT + "." + LinkedObject.FIELD_DATE, startDate)
                    .findAll()
                    .where()
                    .lessThanOrEqualTo(RealmObject.FIELD_LINKED_OBJECT + "." + LinkedObject.FIELD_DATE, endDate)
                    .findAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your timestamps are Strings. In that case you're storing your timestamps incorrectly. When doing > or < etc. on a String, as with a number, you go left to right. 27 is between 01 and 29, so it doesn't matter what figures are after it.

In order to query like that you would need to save from greatest to least value, or YYYY-MM-DD, that way going from left to right will actually compare correctly. Obviously your start and end dates would also have to be in that format. You've already made sure to have leading 0s which is also important.